# Tableau - keeping a sheet static in dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I have 4 sheets that are put up in the tableau dashboard.
Sheet 1: Total no. Of user IDs (population). Text
Sheet 2: total user ids based on selection in sheet 3 and sheet 4.
Sheet 3 & 4: Bar graph of user ids based on company and vendor. Both the sheets are "use as filter"

Sheet 1 has to be static in the dashboard whether we select any filter or when we select any bar on sheet 3 and 4.

Now the issue is when I select any bar on the sheet 3 and 4 both sheet 1 and 2 shows same count.

I have removed all filters from population sheet.

I tried to even ignore action in sheet1, it's still not working

What I want now is what ever the selection is , sheet 1 in the dashboard should be static. Please help.

Regards, Sajan

Answer (score 0):

Try this; 
Check the filters on all the sheets to see if they are set to filter the Data Source, set them, to your preferences.
[image: Tableau Snipped]

If you can (watch out for sensitive data) upload your sheet to Tableau public, it'll be easier to find your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is called an automatically generated action. When you click "use as filter" on a sheet on your dashboard, you're creating an action that affects all other items on that dashboard. Go to the Dashboard, then click on the dashboard menu at the top of the screen, then click "Actions..."

[image: Dashboard Menu]

You should see the filter that you created there. Select the action, then click "edit".

[image: Actions]

You should now see something similar to the below picture. What you need to do for each action (you should have two, one from each sheet that is being used as a filter) is uncheck the static sheet on the list of Target Sheets on the bottom half of the Edit Filter Action dialogue box.

[image: Edit Filter Action]

This will prevent anything happening to the static sheet (in this case, "Count of Employee Transactions") when you click on the sheets being used as filters. [image]